# Find by class name doesn't work in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the value of the info class after the submit button is clicked.

I have the following HTML which is made of many table rows (here displayed two)

```html
<tr> 
   <td scope="row">Name1</td>                                                                     
   <td class="info">Info Text 1</td> 
   <td><input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"></td>   
</tr>
<tr> 
   <td scope="row">Name2</td>                                                                     
   <td class="info">Info Text 2</td> 
   <td><input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"></td>   
</tr>
```

I want to get the value of the info class - `Info Text` in this example.
I try to select it using the following jQuery selector:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find(".info").text();
```

But it gives me blank window when I try to alert the result.

But when I use `next()` it works:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().next().text();
```

Comment: I would just use `$(this).closest('tr').find('.info').text()`...

Comment: Thank you, it works also and I learned a new way to do it with `closest`. Do you have any idea why the first way didn't work? Could it be related to the fact that the real table has multiple rows with the same class? I will update OP to show you

Comment: `find()` searches descendants, not current level. `.info` is a sibling, not a descendant, so it won't be found. You could change it to `filter` and it would work also.

Comment: What is `this`? Context matters also